# Navigating from user control

Tags: c#, user-controls, windows-runtime, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I am writing a **Windows Phone 8.1 app (WINRT)**. I made a **user control**. In this user control i have a **textblock** and on c**licking it i am navigating to FeedbackPage page.**

But the problem is that page is opened twice, i mean it **creates two instances of page in BackStack**.

My code:

```
private void SendFeedback_PointerExited(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
            {

            ((Frame)Window.Current.Content).Navigate(typeof(FeedbackPage));

            }
```

I opened the Main page, then went to AboutPage containing this user control, on clicking the feedback textblock in user control, it goes to feedbackpage twice.
So **Backstack** becomes:
**Mainpage > AboutPage > Feedbackpage > feedbackpage**

I debugged SendFeedback_PointerExited() method, and observed that it **executes twice** and am not able find the reason.

Answer (score 1):

The best event to handle taps is `Tapped` instead of `PointerExited`. `TextBlock` has the event, so you can use it. It will be fired only once.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the `PointerExited` event - instead use the `PointerPressed` event. This will get raised whenever the user clicks / taps on the text.